# Outlook Web Add-in: The element in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1' has invalid child element

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Currently following this guide for activating an outlook add-in without a reading pane enabled or a message selected:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextless

I'm using the "Outlook Web Add-in" project template provided by Visual Studio as my basis which includes a simple MessageRead boilerplate. I'm trying to edit this template so that the add-on button composes a new email message and is visible at any time.

I've tried following the guide, and changed my manifest code to match as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>308e295d-4e63-42c7-a6ef-eb93731d8e3f</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>[Provider name]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="OutlookWebAddIn_Transmittal" />
  <Description DefaultValue="OutlookWebAddIn_Transmittal"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon64.png"/>

  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.contoso.com" />
  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->
  
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Requirements>
                <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.13">
                    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
                </bt:Sets>
            </Requirements>
            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <!-- Message Read mode-->
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                        <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                                            <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl"/>
                                            <!-- Enables your add-in to activate without the Reading Pane enabled or a message selected. -->
                                            <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Images>
                    <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon16.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon32.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon80.png"/>
                </bt:Images>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
                    <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/MessageRead.html"/>
                </bt:Urls>
                <bt:ShortStrings>
                    <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test walkthrough"/>
                    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
                </bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:LongStrings>
                    <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a task pane."/>
                </bt:LongStrings>
            </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

When I attempt to run the code, I receive the following error:
[image]

I've tried troubleshooting various solutions I found such as changing the versionoverides schema version to 1.1 instead of 1.0 and vice-versa.

I've also tried including both versionoverides to no avail.

Let me know if there any solutions to this issue or alternative methods by which I can achieve my desired results.

Comment: What Exchange version are you using? It's possible that you are on an older version of Exchange that the feature is not available.